# Convert a Postgres query into JPQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jpql

I have the following query in Postgres:

```
SELECT *
from table1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN table1.table2 ON table1.latest_id = table2.id
WHERE table1.table2.status = 0
  AND table1.id NOT IN (
    (SELECT id from table3 where userId = table2.user))
```

I do not have the ability to join table1 and table3 and I am stuck writing the subquery in a format JPA will understand - working with a spring boot app. Here is where I got so far in my repository class:

```
  @Query("SELECT c FROM #{#entityName} c JOIN FETCH c.table2 WHERE c.table2.status = 0")
  fun findByIdAndStatus(id: String): MyEntity
```

I have attempted at the subquery as follows, but with no joy - there is a clear syntax error I cannot wrap my head around:

```
    @Query("SELECT c FROM #{#entityName} c JOIN FETCH c.table2 WHERE c.table2.status = 0" AND c.id NOT IN (" +
"SELECT * FROM Table3 WHERE userId = c.table2.user")
```

Can you help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- your SQL query doesn't utilize any input arguments
- table1 is mapped by `MyEntity` and table3 is mapped by `Table3` entity
- entity associated with table2 is mapped in `MyEntity` using `latest_id` join column
- status is mapped as a number (i.e Long / Integer)

You can rewrite the query to following JPQL form:

```
    @Query("SELECT t1 FROM MyEntity t1 "
            + "JOIN t1.table2 t2 "
            + "WHERE t2.status = 0 AND t1.id NOT IN ("
            + "       SELECT t3.id from Table3 t3 "
            + "       WHERE t3.userId = t2.user "
            + ")")
    List<MyEntity> findMyEntities();
```

Comment: Thank for your reply. I actually use an input arguments which is t1.id. How would that affect my JPQL query?

Comment: In such case you just need to add in outer `where` a condition for `t1.id = :identifier` and alter method signature by adding `Long identifier` argument.